# UITableView - setting cell contents based on index path

Tags: xcode, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:... cellForRowAtIndexPath:... {
    // init and sanity check

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        // make cell look like a section header
        // easier and less complex than using a custom header view

        NSLog(@"header");
        // should prove that only four cells get the bg image
        // and yet, almost every time the table is reloaded
        // one more cell unexpectedly gets the background
        // without putting another line in the debugger
    } else {
        // normal cells after row 0
        // BUG: some of these are getting the row 0 background

        NSLog(@"row");
        // firing exactly the right number of times --
        // once for each row with an index greater than 0
        // so why are some of these cells getting the header bg?

        // when these cells get the headers' contents
        // they behave exactly as one would expect
        // except that they should be the normal rows
    }

    // misc stuff, not causing problems

    return cell;
}
```

Short of forcing the user to completely relaunch the app just to have different data dumped into the table, I can't figure out how to fix the bug.

The problem is less severe if I collapse every section (that is, empty the `expandedSections` set and reload, leaving only the pseudo-headers visible), but it doesn't go away.

---

**Edit:**

Initial load: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts5tt.png)
After reloading: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3VDV.png)
Links instead of images because it's an iPad app.
Using some dummy content for testing.

Is this any help? I know there needs to be more code for serious help, but I don't know what else to add, short of a link to the code for the entire view.

Comment: So it's "easier and less complex" to abuse the data source, rather than using a custom header view? Sounds like it given you are having issues.

Comment: You can't have 0 rows in a section. I want to be able to show the headers but not the rows in certain sections, and allow the user to choose which are expanded/collapsed on the fly. It's a necessary implementation, and much nicer looking than any alternatives I can think of.

Comment: What "abusing" are you talking about, and how would your implementation look?

Comment: have you tried setting a different cell identifier for the first cell and another one for the rest of them?

Comment: I'll give that a shot, Andrei.

Comment: Also, it might help adding the full code for cellForRow

Comment: @Andrei Absolutely perfect, as far as I can tell. Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting a different cell identifier for the first cell and another one for the rest of them?
The tableView reuses the same cell type when creating new cells so it might get them mixed up. By using different cell identifiers for each type, it will know exactly when to use each cell.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to the cell cache...something about setting the image for row == 0 and not clearing it otherwise...but with the limited amount of code you're showing it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: `cell.backgroundView = nil;` is harmless for the cells that are loading properly. For those that get the header background (even though `indexPath.row` is greater than 0), the only difference is that instead of an image, it's just a white block. Text looks wrong and the header accessory is still there. Doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Well, it proves that it is a cache problem.  That is, when you configure things for the == 0 case, you're not clearing them out or replacing them for > 0.  (The fact that there are more things than just the image wasn't something I could have guessed from your question.)